# jQuery form validation - Check if emails are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a jQuery form validator for my website.

My code is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EPu3D/2/).

The question is, what do I need to do, so that I can check if the email is the same as the email confirmation when both fields have valid email addresses?

Also, since I'm currently learning javascript/jQuery, feel free to point out any mistakes|bad practices on my code.

Comment: @Radu You suggest I had an array of input id's, regex for the input value, and error message, and did something like array.each(//call function to bind event handler here)? If not could you please help me by giving me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#signupform").on('submit', function(e) {
    var email = $("#email_ID").val(),
        confirm = $("#email_confirm_ID").val();

    if (email!=confirm) {
       alert('email and confirm are not equal!');
       e.preventDefault(); //form will not be submitted
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the delayed response. Will test and return to award rep.